add images in \longtable and remove justification
I'm a beginner in LaTex but i've used longtable before. Now i'm trying to add images inside the table but i can't make them fit the cells. I don't want to make them smaller, i'd like to make the rows bigger.
I also can't get the text to not be justified, I want it to be left aligned. Can someone help me??
Here's my MWE:
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}     
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}                   
\usepackage{graphicx}             
\usepackage{geometry}                   
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx, blindtext}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{small}
    \centering
\setlength\aboverulesep{0pt}
\setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}
\setlength\doublerulesep{0pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{0pt}
\taburulecolor{black}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{longtable}[l]{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash} m{0.16\textwidth}|m{0.18\textwidth}|m{0.2\textwidth}|m{0.17\textwidth}|m{0.16\textwidth}|}
    \toprule
    {\textbf{Abreviation} & \textbf{Optical Component Name} & \textbf{Model} & \textbf{Dimensions [mm]} & \textbf{Materials}} \\ 
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    \endhead
    {OBJECTIVE} & Objective Lens & \includegraphics[scale=0.18]{Fotos/Lens objective.png} & $\diameter$25 & 7980 Fused Silica \\ \hline
    {FSM} & Fast Steering Mirror & \includegraphics[scale=0.15]{Fotos/FSM Mirror.png} & 20x14.14 & Sintered SiC \\ \hline
     {BS} & Wide Field 4QD Beamsplitter & \includegraphics[scale=0.18]{Fotos/Wide Field 4QD Beamsplitter.png} & 10x10 & 7980 Fused Silica \\ \hline
     {-} & 4QD Filter & \includegraphics[scale=0.17]{Fotos/Comm. Channel Filter.png} & $\diameter$5 &  \\ \hline
     {-} & Comm. Channel Barlow & \includegraphics[scale=0.17]{Fotos/Comm. Channel Barlow.png} & $\diameter$6 & 7980 Fused Silica \\ \hline
     {NF 4QD} & Narrow Field Four Quadrant Detector G6849 & \includegraphics[scale=0.17]{Fotos/4QD.png} & $\diameter$2 Área activa &  \\ \hline
     {WF 4QD} & Wide Field Four Quadrant Detector G6849 & \includegraphics[scale=0.17]{Fotos/4QD.png} & $\diameter$2 Área activa &  \\ \hline
     {APD} & Avalanche Photodiode FD05D & \includegraphics[scale=0.28]{Fotos/APD.png} & $\diameter$0.5 Área activa &  \\ 
     \bottomrule
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:my_label}

\end{longtable}
\end{small}


\end{document}

And this is the table I get:


I accept all types of criticism. Thanks!!!

Welcome to TeX.SE.

Don't use the tabu package unless you really know what you are doing. It is currently not maintained.

@JasperHabicht i added it to use \taburulecolor{darkblue} in another table (i read it somewhere), i don't know if i can replace it with something else

I don't really know the tabu package, but if you need colored table rules, you probably should take a look at the colortbl package and use \arrayrulecolor instead.

Something like this?


Package tabu is obsolete, many of its features can be find in tabularray package (but not with the same syntax).
I assume, that all images have equal size.
For inserting of images are used \adjincludegraphics of adjustbox. By it is simpler to define images size and positions of their baseline.
Regarding to size of table (generated by your table code) can be concluded, that table is shorter than one page, so it is not need that it be longtable (anyway I consider that for some unknown reason it should be used).
Instead of longtable I suggest to use \longtblr of tabularray package. Using it the table code is shorter and to my opinion more clear and simple.

\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}     
\usepackage{geometry}                   

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}        % not used in this MWE
\usepackage{wasysym}
%\usepackage{ragged2e}  % not used in this MWE

\usepackage[demo,       % remove in resl document
            export]{adjustbox}  % for "valign",  also load graphicx
\usepackage{tabularray}


\begin{document}
{
\adjustboxset{width=\linewidth,
              keepaspectratio,
              valign=M}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Caption},
  label = {longtab:my label},
                ]{hlines, vlines,
                  colspec = {Q[l] X[1.2,l,m] *{3}{X[l,m]} },
                  cell{2, 5-Z}{4} = {preto =$\diameter$\;},
                  row{1}  = {font=\small\bfseries, c},
                  rowhead = 1
                  }
% column headers
Abbreviation    &   Optical Component Name
                    &   Model 
                        &   Dimensions [mm]
                            &   Materials               \\ 
% table body
OBJECTIVE   &   Objective Lens 
                &   \adjincludegraphics{Fotos/Lens objective.png} 
                    &   25 
                        &   7980 Fused Silica       \\
FSM         &   Fast Steering Mirror 
                &   \adjincludegraphics{Fotos/FSM Mirror.png} 
                    &   20x14.14 
                        & Sintered SiC              \\
BS          &   Wide Field 4QD Beamsplitter 
                &   \adjincludegraphics{Fotos/Wide Field 4QD Beamsplitter.png} 
                    & 10x10 
                        & 7980 Fused Silica        \\
--          &   4QD Filter 
                &   \adjincludegraphics{Fotos/Comm. Channel Filter.png} 
                    &   5 
                        &                           \\
--          &   Comm. Channel Barlow 
                &   \adjincludegraphics{Fotos/Comm. Channel Barlow.png} 
                    &   6 
                        & 7980 Fused Silica         \\ 
NF 4QD      &   Narrow Field Four Quadrant Detector G6849 
                &   \adjincludegraphics{Fotos/4QD.png} 
                    &   2 Área activa 
                        &                           \\
WF 4QD      &   Wide Field Four Quadrant Detector G6849 
                &   \adjincludegraphics{Fotos/4QD.png} 
                    &    2 Área activa 
                        &                           \\
APD         &   Avalanche Photodiode FD05D 
                &   \adjincludegraphics{Fotos/APD.png} 
                    &    0.5 Área activa 
                        &                           \\
\end{longtblr}
}
\end{document}


I think the OP wants \diameter, not \phi.

@Mico, yes it is in her/his code. To me are looking very similar (at technical drawing in high school we use phi for denoted diameters :-) ), however is not difficult replace it with diameter.  I will do this ASAP.

@Zarko Yes! That works perfect.  I'll start replacing the longtable packaging in the future. Thank you so much :)

@Zarko hi again, is there any way to remove or change the language of the 'Continued on next page' phrase? My document is not in English, and I already have the babel package written

@Lids, tabularray package support some languages. which, I need to check documentation.  I'm on phone now, so I will do this late evening. Of course, you can do this yourself too

@Zarko got it hehe link   this worked :)

@Lids, I need to correct myself. tabularray itself not support other languages than English, however add-on package tblr-extras does. Currently only spanish, italian, portuguese, ngerman, russian, ukrainian and french. If your language is one of them, I can write new/additional answer where I would show this posibilities

@Zarko it's spanish!

@Lids, ok. I will wrote this ASAP (afternoon)


I also can't get the text to not be justified, I want it to be left aligned.

I would like to suggest that you switch from a longtable to an xltabular environment. The latter combines the capabilities of the longtable (span more than one page) and tabularx (set an overall target width, e.g., \textwidth) environments. Separately, given the minor differences in column widths, I think you might as well require that all 5 columns have the same width. And, use a prefix instruction such as \RaggedRight to suppress (full) justification.
In addition, I'd give the table a more open and inviting look -- by getting rid of all vertical rules and by using fewer, but well-spaced, horizontal rules, by employing the line-drawing macros of the booktabs package.
The following screenshot shows the first couple of rows of the resulting table.

\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
%%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % new
%%%\usepackage{multicol} % are you sure about this?
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{colortbl}
%%%\usepackage{tabu} % you can't be serious
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{wasysym}

% new:
%\usepackage{longtable,tabularx}
\usepackage{xltabular} % combine the capabilities of 'longtable' and 'tabularx'
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}} % default is the 'p' column type
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X} % suppress full justification, allow hyphenation

\begin{document}

%%%\begin{small} % why?
%%%\centering
%\setlength\aboverulesep{0pt}
%\setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}
%\setlength\doublerulesep{0pt}
%\setlength\extrarowheight{0pt}
%%%\taburulecolor{black}
%%%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} *{5}{L} @{}}
   
    \caption{Caption} \label{tab:my_label}\\
    \toprule
    \textbf{Abreviation} & \textbf{Optical Component Name} & \textbf{Model} & \textbf{Dimensions [mm]} & \textbf{Materials} \\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead

    \midrule
    \endhead
    
    \midrule
    \endfoot
    
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot

    OBJECTIVE & Objective Lens & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Fotos/Lens objective.png} & $\diameter$25 & 7980 Fused Silica \\ \addlinespace
    FSM & Fast Steering Mirror & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Fotos/FSM Mirror.png} & 20$\times$14.14 & Sintered SiC \\ \addlinespace
    BS & Wide Field 4QD Beamsplitter & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Fotos/Wide Field 4QD Beamsplitter.png} & 10$\times$10 & 7980 Fused Silica \\ \addlinespace
    -- & 4QD Filter & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Fotos/Comm. Channel Filter.png} & $\diameter$5 &  \\ \addlinespace
    -- & Comm. Channel Barlow & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Fotos/Comm. Channel Barlow.png} & $\diameter$6 & 7980 Fused Silica \\ \addlinespace
    NF 4QD & Narrow Field Four Quadrant Detector G6849 & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Fotos/4QD.png} & $\diameter$2 Área activa &  \\ \addlinespace
    WF 4QD & Wide Field Four Quadrant Detector G6849 & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Fotos/4QD.png} & $\diameter$2 Área activa &  \\ \addlinespace
    APD & Avalanche Photodiode FD05D & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Fotos/APD.png} & $\diameter$0.5 Área activa &  \\

\end{xltabular}

%%%\end{small}

\end{document} 


yeah it looks a bit cleaner, i'll try both and see which one fits better. thanks a lot! :)

@Lids, for start you can award both answer with up-vote (clicking on up-triangle at top left side of answers)  and than select one which the best fit to your expectation

Regarding your question about change the language of the 'Continued on next page' phrase? translation (an table label) in your comment:
Another possibilities is to use package  tblr-extras which enable to use caption package and its styles option for caption in the longtblr and talltablr tables as well to support babel for languages  spanish, italian, portuguese, ngerman, russian, ukrainian and french (so far).
AN example:
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}     
\usepackage{geometry}                   
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}     % added

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\usepackage[demo,               % remove in resl document
            export]{adjustbox}  % for "valign",  also load graphicx
            
\usepackage[skip=1ex, 
            labelfont=bf]{caption}            % if you wish to define table caption with
                                % caption˛package defined styles/options            
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tblr-extras}        % added,  for caption styles in longtblr and talltbor
\UseTblrLibrary{babel, caption} % added

\usepackage{lipsum}             % for dummy text before longtbl

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]                    % to move the table down to split between two pages
{
\adjustboxset{width=\linewidth,
              keepaspectratio,
              valign=M}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Caption},
  label = {longtab:my label},
                ]{hlines, vlines,
                  colspec = {Q[l] X[1.2,l,m] *{3}{X[l,m]} },
                  cell{2, 5-Z}{4} = {preto =$\diameter$\;},
                  row{1}  = {font=\small\bfseries, c},
                  rowhead = 1
                  }
% column headers
Abbreviation    &   Optical Component Name
                    &   Model 
                        &   Dimensions [mm]
                            &   Materials               \\ 
% table body
OBJECTIVE   &   Objective Lens 
                &   \adjincludegraphics{Fotos/Lens objective.png} 
                    &   25 
                        &   7980 Fused Silica       \\
FSM         &   Fast Steering Mirror 
                &   \adjincludegraphics{Fotos/FSM Mirror.png} 
                    &   20x14.14 
                        & Sintered SiC              \\
BS          &   Wide Field 4QD Beamsplitter 
                &   \adjincludegraphics{Fotos/Wide Field 4QD Beamsplitter.png} 
                    & 10x10 
                        & 7980 Fused Silica        \\
--          &   4QD Filter 
                &   \adjincludegraphics{Fotos/Comm. Channel Filter.png} 
                    &   5 
                        &                           \\
--          &   Comm. Channel Barlow 
                &   \adjincludegraphics{Fotos/Comm. Channel Barlow.png} 
                    &   6 
                        & 7980 Fused Silica         \\ 
NF 4QD      &   Narrow Field Four Quadrant Detector G6849 
                &   \adjincludegraphics{Fotos/4QD.png} 
                    &   2 Área activa 
                        &                           \\
WF 4QD      &   Wide Field Four Quadrant Detector G6849 
                &   \adjincludegraphics{Fotos/4QD.png} 
                    &    2 Área activa 
                        &                           \\
APD         &   Avalanche Photodiode FD05D 
                &   \adjincludegraphics{Fotos/APD.png} 
                    &    0.5 Área activa 
                        &                           \\
\end{longtblr}
}
\end{document}



you're a genius thank you so much

@Lids,  you are welcome!

Can I ask you one last question? hehe, If I had to reduce the width of the entire table, how could I do it? I am applying this code in another similar table but with only 2 columns and I can't find anything

@Lids, you can define width of table with option width = <desired width>. Beside this, you can define width of columns (wd=<desired width>, etc. I got a feeling that is now come a time that you at least briefly read documentation of package . It has 186 pages however, tabularray offers many design options. Documentation is concise with many examples. Anyway, for new table ask new (follow-up) question where explain what is new problem.
